# Netty4 - Pass information between handlers in the same pipeline with executors

Tags: netty

I`m relatively new to Netty. I'm trying to pass information between my handlers in a pipeline. Initially, I was using Channel Attributes:

```
context.channel().attr(MY_ATTRIB).set(value);
context.channel().attr(MY_ATTRIB).get();
```

This worked as I expected but when I added EventExecuters for some Handlers:

```
DefaultEventExecutorGroup eventExecutor = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(64);
...
pipeline.addLast(eventExecutor, new MyHandler());
```

things got messed up.

So my question:

Am I correct that I cannot use Channel Attributes to exchange stateful information **between** handlers in a pipeline when I'm using EventExecuterGroups?

And if yes, what other options do I have to do that?

Comment: Do you have example code? Attributes on the pipeline can be passed between handles even when using executor groups.